# How to catch JVM_Bind exception: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Tags: java, exception

How can i catch the Bind exception? i used the following lines

```
try{
    //some code
}
catch (java.net.BindException e) {
    //some code
}
```

and

```
try{
    //some code
}catch (BindException e) {
    //some code
}
```

but none of them is working giving me the error

```
`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
...
```

Can anybody give me an idea? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If this is coming from a debugging port, I don't think this is possible, as the port is being opened by the JVM itself, and the JVM code that opens the port is executed before your main method is called.

Comment: What code is causing the exception? Please add a stack trace of the error to your question.

Comment: @GreenGiant thanks for answering. I edited the post

Comment: @Anja.M sorry, pressed enter inadvertently. Please see my answer

Comment: @yair i saw it, thank you. I will have a look now

Comment: Try catching Throwable, it should catch just about anything

Comment: The code you posted does not exhibit the problem you describe. Post the *real* code, or an extract from it, and enough of the stack trace to prove that it comes from something in the `try` block. Which, obviously, it doesn't.

Comment: You'll need to post the full stack trace. The part you posted doesn't show the information we need to help you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Are you sure that the `try` block surrounds the code that throws the exception? I say, either it's not, or that the `BindException` is wrapped with some other `Throwable` before thrown. In that case, try

```
try {
    // the problematic code
} catch (Throwable t) { // <--- here, Throwable
   // better log the error here
}
```

Comment: This code block does not appear to work. I am using it to catch a BindException in code that I *know* is surrounded by a try block that throws the exception. The exception is not caught in the catch block whether I am catching a BindException or a Throwable.

Comment: @FactorThree you're welcome to post the code and I'm sure that someone in Stackoverflow, maybe me, would be helpful.

Comment: @FactorThree regrading that this try..catch doesn't catch the BIndException, one possible reason could that some other `catch` block already catches the exception and doesn't re-throw it.

Comment: @FactorThree And one last thing, if you're the downvoter then it kind of makes me sad. First off, this code block definitely works per-se - it catches any Exception/Error/Throwable that a Java app can throw and **that arrives to it** up the stack-trace... Second, this worked for the asked question as this answer was accepted... Third, IMHO downvoting when an accepted answer doesn't work in your particular case - is harsh and probably misleading, especially when the question and answer are 9 months old.

Comment: Irrelevant. The code was presented as working to catch this exception. I set up a simple network stream to test it. It did not work. Period.

Comment: That having been said, I am happy  to provide the test code I used. It is entirely possible that something else did indeed catch the BindException. Trouble is, if network streaming or NIO classes do internally catch this exception, then there is no way that the code block can work. Still, if indeed that was the problem or a working solution can be found, I will be happy to remove my down- vote...

Comment: @FactorThree nothing in my answer - nor in the original question - implies that **any** code put into the `try` would or should catch any `BindException` that is not fully thrown. It is your test case (that I expected you to post by now) that is actually irrelevant...

Comment: @FactorThree and really I don't care much about the vote, but you _could_ debug your test case - which you say is simple - and verify whether the `BindException` is internally caught or not, before down-voting or commenting in such a harsh manner. When people help on their spare time, that's not a way to react.